# rowSums over different columns for each row

Tags: r, dplyr, rowsum

I would like to perform a `rowSums()` over specified columns. My trouble is that the desired columns to sum over are different for each row and given by another variable. The motivation is to check whether the three values before a given column are NA.

An example data frame can be built by

```
toy <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10)),
                  day = c(1:10, 1:10, 1:10),
                  response = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1,
                          1, 1, NA, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1,
                          NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  colnum = c(rep(5, 10), rep(7, 10), rep(10, 10)))
toy <- toy %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 2, values_from = 3, names_prefix = "day")
toy
```

In this example, the `colnum` variable gives the day for which to check the previous three days. Looking at the data,

```
toy
# A tibble: 3 x 12
     id colnum  day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  day6  day7  day8  day9 day10
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      5     1    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1    NA    NA     1
2     2      7     1     1    NA     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
3     3     10    NA     1    NA     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I would want to create a new column in the data frame which would have values of `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `FALSE` for ids 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Let's call it `three_miss`. E.g., for id=1, we want to check if days 2 through 4 are all NA since colnum=5.
I tried a simple implementation of rowSums()

```
 toy <- toy %>% mutate(three_miss = rowSums(select(., (colnum-1):(colnum+1)), na.rm = TRUE) == 3)
```

Using `colnum-1:colnum+1` was deduced by which column numbers we would need. The code will run but gives `FALSE` for all values of `three_miss`, which is not the correct or desired output. I receive warning messages:

```
There were 2 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
i In argument: `three_miss = ==...`.
Caused by warning in `x:y`:
! numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

I get the sense from this that either the `select()` is causing the issue, or `rowSums()` is producing more than one sum per row. I have tried adding `group_by(id)` which does not help. I want to stay within the context of piping, but I am open to other solutions if this is not possible.

p.s. I understand there may be issues if `colnum` is less than 4 or greater than 10. I was planning to amend this by using `case_when()`. E.g.,

```
toy <- toy %>% mutate(three_miss =
  case_when(
    colnum <=3 ~ NA,
    colnum > 10 ~ NA,
    TRUE ~ code_that_works
  )
)
```

Comment: perhaps just keep your data in long format, which is usually easier to deal with, then you can simply: `filter(toy, between(day, colnum-3, colnum-1)) %>% summarize(three_miss=!anyNA(response), .by =id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `toy0` is the data before pivoting, you can do

```r
toy0 %>%
  filter(between(day, colnum-3, colnum-1)) %>%
  summarize(three_wise = all(!is.na(response)), .by = id) %>%
  left_join(toy, ., by = "id")
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#      id colnum  day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  day6  day7  day8  day9 day10 three_wise
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     
# 1     1      5     1    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1    NA    NA     1 FALSE     
# 2     2      7     1     1    NA     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 TRUE      
# 3     3     10    NA     1    NA     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE
```

Comment: Accepting as this accomplishes the crux of my question. I think adding `%>%
  mutate(three_wise = ifelse(colnum <=3 | colnum > 10, NA, three_wise))` after the `left_join()` further handles if there is not three full days to check per the p.s. in my original post. Although, I can imagine scenarios where you would want to check say, just day 1 and 2 supposing colnum=3